# $(-n-1)$-connected spectra vs. reduced excisive functors from $n$-truncated pointed spaces

Tags: homotopy-theory, infinity-categories, higher-algebra

It's possible to view nonconnectivity for spectra as arising from enlarging Segal's category $\Gamma^\mathsf{op}\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\mathsf{Sk}(\mathrm{FinSets}_*)$ to the $\infty$-category of finite pointed spaces $\mathcal{S}^\mathrm{fin}_*$, see [Dmitri's answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/402050).

I'm interested on whether the following refinement of this statement is true:

> We have an equivalence of $\infty$-categories
> $$\mathsf{Exc}_*(\mathcal{S}^{\mathrm{fin}}_{\leq n,*},\mathcal{S})\overset{\mathrm{eq.}}{\cong}\mathsf{Sp}_{\geq-n},$$
> where
>
> - $\mathsf{Exc}_*(\mathcal{S}^{\mathrm{fin}}_{\leq n,*},\mathcal{S})$ is the $\infty$-category of reduced excisive functors from the $\infty$-category $\mathcal{S}^{\mathrm{fin}}_{\leq n,*}$ of finite $n$-truncated pointed spaces;
> - $\mathsf{Sp}_{\geq-n}$ is the $\infty$-category of $(-n-1)$-connected spectra.

The $n=0$ case of the above statement is true; again, see [Dmitri's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/402050).

---

Additionally, we have a fully faithful inclusion of $\infty$-categories $\iota\colon\mathcal{S}^{\mathrm{fin}}_{\leq n,*}\hookrightarrow\mathcal{S}^{\mathrm{fin}}_{*}$, giving functors
\begin{align*}
\iota^* &\colon \mathsf{Sp}\to\mathsf{Exc}_*(\mathcal{S}^{\mathrm{fin}}_{\leq n,*},\mathcal{S}),\\
\mathrm{Lan}_{\iota} &\colon \mathsf{Exc}_*(\mathcal{S}^{\mathrm{fin}}_{\leq n,*},\mathcal{S})\to\mathsf{Sp},\\
\mathrm{Ran}_{\iota} &\colon \mathsf{Exc}_*(\mathcal{S}^{\mathrm{fin}}_{\leq n,*},\mathcal{S})\to\mathsf{Sp}.
\end{align*}
If we indeed have $\mathsf{Exc}_*(\mathcal{S}^{\mathrm{fin}}_{\leq n,*},\mathcal{S})\overset{\mathrm{eq.}}{\cong}\mathsf{Sp}_{\geq-n}$ as above, it would be natural to wonder if $\iota^*$ is just $(-n-1)$-truncation of spectra. If the above quoted statement is true, is $\iota^*$ indeed given by $(-n-1)$-truncation? What about $\mathrm{Lan}_{\iota}$ and $\mathrm{Ran}_{\iota}$?

Comment: The case $n=0$ is far from true: every 1-excisive functor $\mathrm{Fin}_*\to \mathcal S$ is constant...

Comment: $n$-connective spectra are reduced excisive functors $\mathcal S^\mathrm{fin}_*\to\mathcal S$ that increase connectivity by at least $n$. A statement which I think goes in the direction you want is that such functors are determined by their restriction to finite wedges of spheres $S^k$ with $k\leq n$. In particular they are determined by their restriction to finite pointed spaces of *homotopy dimension* $\leq n$, which is very different from $n$-truncated spaces.

Comment: $n$ became $-n$ in the middle of my previous comment, but hopefully what I meant is clear.

Comment: @MarcHoyois Oh right, I completely misunderstood Dmitri's answer. Also, the statement you mentioned about homotopy dimension goes precisely in the direction I wanted. Thanks!